how to add audio track to video with multiple audio & subtitle tracks?
I have a video with 3 audio streams and 4 subtitle streams, all switchable with the QuickTime player. Now I want to add English audio that will also appear in that switchable list.
Here are the streams:
#0x0 video
#0x1 ita audio
#0x2 fra audio
#0x3 ger audio
#0x4 eng subtitle
#0x5 ita subtitle
#0x6 fra subtitle
#0x7 ger subtitle

When I tried this:
ffmpeg -i m.mp4 -i eng.mp3 -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a:0 -metadata:s:a:3 language=eng out.mp4

It added the english audio, but removed subtitles from the switchable list. Here was the stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:4 (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))

When I tried this:
ffmpeg -i m.mp4 -i eng.mp3 -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s -map 1:a:0 -metadata:s:a:3 language=eng -c copy out.mp4

it seemed to add an eng.mp3 stream, but it doesn’t show up in the switchable list. Here was the stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (copy)
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:5 (copy)
  Stream #0:6 -> #0:6 (copy)
  Stream #0:7 -> #0:7 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:8 (copy)

Edit:
At the suggestion of @Rotem I also tried this:
ffmpeg -y -i m.mp4 -i eng.mp3 -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a:0 -map 0:s -metadata:s:a:3 language=eng -c copy out.mp4

but english audio was not added to the switchable list. Here was the stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:4 (copy)
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:5 (copy)
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:6 (copy)
  Stream #0:6 -> #0:7 (copy)
  Stream #0:7 -> #0:8 (copy)

I think maybe I have to re-encode, but honestly, I don't understand what that is and certainly don't understand the ffmpeg commands to do it. I tried using an eng.m4a file (aac) but it didn't work either.
Thanks for any help.

I don't know if it's going to work. Try switching the mapping order: ffmpeg -y -i m.mp4 -i eng.mp3 -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a:0 -map 0:s -metadata:s:a:3 language=eng -c copy out.mp4

@Rotem I tried what you suggested but it did not add the english audio -- at least not in the switchable list. ffmpeg - out.mp4 shows it's there. I'm stumped. Thanks anyway. I also tried removing the "-c copy" part and it gave this error: "Automatic encoder selection failed Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually." But I don't know how to do that

What do you see under Stream mapping: in the ffmpeg's output though? (Please add it to your post by editing.)

@TomYan the stream mapping for each command are now added to the original post

Since no solution was offered, I assume my goal in the original post cannot be achieved in one step.
So, I used the following work-around.:

add the English audio with the first command in the orignal post:
ffmpeg -i m.mp4 -i eng.mp3 -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a:0 -metadata:s:a:3 language=eng out.mp4

since the above removed the 4 subtitle streams, re-add them with:
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -i eng.srt -i ita.srt -i fre.srt -i ger.srt -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:s:0  -map 2:s:0 -map 3:s:0 -map 4:s:0 -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=ita -metadata:s:s:2 language=fra -metadata:s:s:3 language=ger -c:s:0 mov_text -c:s:1 mov_text -c:s:2 mov_text -c:s:3 mov_text -shortest final.mp4


The result was a video which could be switched between 4 audio and 4 subtitle languages
